# Prompted for FTP details even with FS_DIRECT set to true

Tags: plugins, installation, permissions, nginx

I am running WordPress 4.1 Multisite on CentOS with NGINX. I have set `define('FS_METHOD','direct');` in `wp-config.php` but am still getting prompted for FTP credentials when trying to install a plugin.

I have tried chmod'ing the `wp-content` directories *recursively* with both `nginx` and `www-data` users and neither works

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Because I had cut and pasted `define(’FS_METHOD’,’direct’);` from the web, the incorrect quote characters were pasted into the file.

should be `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');`

The incorrect quote character also changed the encoding of the file somehow. If anyone has deeper knowledge of this issue please let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write define('FS_METHOD', 'direct'); in wp-config.php.
Make sure you can add this line just after define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );

So it will look like the following.

```
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

See this Video
https://youtu.be/Jrqta7eYfsg